# Randomize demographic values and retain the same information for similar IDs

Tags: r

New to R and learning my ropes.

| Subject_ID | Age | Gender | Ethnicity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 27 | Male | White |
| A1 | 27 | Male | White |
| C2 | 22 | Female | Asian |
| D3 | 40 | Male | Black |
| R4 | 25 | Female | Asian |
| R4 | 25 | Female | Asian |

How to randomize the variables above so that same randomized values apply to same subject ids?

Comment: do you mean randomly order the rows?

Comment: We need to randomize the Age, Gender, ethnicity variables so that they don't belong to a true original ID.

Comment: You might find {uuid} helpful: https://www.rforge.net/uuid/docs/index.html (note that an unsecured translation table will compromise any fancy hash creation just the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to randomize all the demographics independently, but maintain their consistency across IDs, you could do:

```r
set.seed(1) # Makes example reproducible

df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) {
  rep(sample(unique(x), length(unique(df[[1]])), TRUE),
      times = rle(df[[1]])$lengths)})

df
#>   Subject_ID Age Gender Ethnicity
#> 1         A1  27 Female     Asian
#> 2         A1  27 Female     Asian
#> 3         C2  25   Male     Asian
#> 4         D3  40   Male     Black
#> 5         R4  27   Male     Black
#> 6         R4  27   Male     Black
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(Subject_ID = c("A1", "A1", "C2", "D3", "R4", "R4"
), Age = c(27L, 27L, 22L, 40L, 25L, 25L), Gender = c("Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female"), Ethnicity = c("White", 
"White", "Asian", "Black", "Asian", "Asian")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df
#>   Subject_ID Age Gender Ethnicity
#> 1         A1  27   Male     White
#> 2         A1  27   Male     White
#> 3         C2  22 Female     Asian
#> 4         D3  40   Male     Black
#> 5         R4  25 Female     Asian
#> 6         R4  25 Female     Asian
```